# How can I drop a stored procedure whose name is in a variable?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, stored-procedures, t-sql

Given a variable that contains a stored procedure name:

```
DECLARE @stored_procedure_name sysname;
SET @stored_procedure_name = 'some_stored_procedure_name';
```

How can I drop the stored procedure?

Comment: @PaulWhite, I have a situation where as part of an application's DB deployment script, it should execute and drop a set of stored procedures. I'm using this approach due to the way the tools I'm using work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To do this, you must use dynamic SQL, as the statement `DROP PROCEDURE` cannot be parameterized.

As a bit of an aside, it's a good practice to always schema-qualify object names. You didn't specify the schema name in the question (or say that the variable contains a complete dot-separated name), so I've gone ahead and extended what you asked for to include it.

```
DECLARE @stored_procedure_schema sysname = NULL;
DECLARE @stored_procedure_name sysname = N'some_stored_procedure_name';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX) =
    N'DROP PROCEDURE ' +
        ISNULL(QUOTENAME(@stored_procedure_schema) + N'.', N'') +
        QUOTENAME(@stored_procedure_name) + N';';

EXEC(@sql);
```

This doesn't do any checking to see if the procedure actually exists or not before it attempts to drop it, so you'll get an error if it doesn't exist. It's trivial to use `sys.procedures` to check for existence, so I didn't bother with that, and you didn't ask for it either.

To preemptively answer your comment on the other answers, [`QUOTENAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) will correctly escape any object name such that it ends up surrounded by square brackets. Specifically, yes, this does handle single quotes (and square brackets) within the procedure name itself.

Answer (score 4):

Use dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql varchar(64);

set @sql = 'drop proc ' + @stored_procedure_name;

exec(@sql);
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it escapes the stored procedure name; wouldn't this break if the stored procedure name variable contained `'`?

Answer (score 4):

Dynamic SQL

EDIT:

Simple version with `QUOTENAME` added

```
DECLARE @stored_procedure_name sysname;
SET @stored_procedure_name = 'some_stored_procedure_name';
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @sql = 'DROP PROCEDURE ' + QUOTENAME(@stored_procedure_name)
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Slightly more complex version with `schema name variable`, `QUOTENAME` and test for the existence of the stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @stored_procedure_name sysname;
DECLARE @stored_procedure_schema sysname;

SET @stored_procedure_name = 'mytest';
IF ISNULL(@stored_procedure_schema,'') = ''
    SET @stored_procedure_schema = 'DBO';

DECLARE @object_name sysname;
SET @object_name = QUOTENAME(@stored_procedure_schema) + '.' +
    QUOTENAME(@stored_procedure_name);

IF OBJECT_ID(@object_name) <> 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
    SET @sql = 'DROP PROCEDURE ' + @object_name;
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it escapes the stored procedure name; wouldn't this break if the stored procedure name variable contained `'`?

Comment: Good point @Sam.  I've added `QUOTENAME` and a bit more.